# Convert string field 'Wednesday, January 30th, 2013, 1:02 PM' to date in mySQL and replace an adjascent field

Tags: mysql

I have a table `TableA` with two fields, `strField` and `dateField`. The string field strField  has text dates like **Wednesday, January 30th, 2013, 1:02 PM** in it, but I need to convert that to a date format and replace it in the adjacent field called `dateField`. Is there a simple way of doing this or do I have to do all the stripping ?

The last step is easy, I think. When I strip everything and get the string to look like this *2013-02-15 11:45:21.0* it will be just a simple

```
STR_TO_DATE('2013-02-15 11:45:21.0', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Perhaps there is a function which can strip the data easily and reformat the original text string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT( 
  STR_TO_DATE( 'Wednesday, January 30th, 2013, 1:02 PM', '%W, %M %D, %Y, %I:%i %p' ), '%Y-%m-%d %T');
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e792d/4) link.

For other format conversions, check the [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) at MySQL docs.

---

For your `UPDATE` this would do:

```
UPDATE `tableA`
SET `dateField` =  DATE_FORMAT(
        STR_TO_DATE(`strField`, '%W, %M %D, %Y, %I:%i %p'),
    '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Comment: You rock, Back in a Flash!